# How to walk around Apple's sandboxing?

Tags: swift, macos, dock, appstore-sandbox

I'm developing an app, which main functionality relies on editing this system file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

It would be great to sell it through App Store. Is it possible to walk around sandboxing somehow just to read and write this file?

Comment: Have you looked into `NSOpenPanel` to make the user choose the file so you can access it?

Comment: @Purpose it's not so user friendly way to do it. 

Comment: have you verified that editing this plist file actually can add an item to the dock?

Comment: @Michael, sure! You can do with dock whatever you want 

Comment: so you figured that format out. really? So, when you add an item there, it magically appears in the dock, right? I already tried this out in the past, it does not work.

Comment: You should try to find a way to add an icon to the dock before looking for ways to work around the sandboxing.

Comment: You could beg the user to make the app a system-app and then beg on your knees the app-review people to approve. I‘m not sure it will work though, just an idea to keep in mind. Or just distribute it yourself..

Comment: @Purpose I'm near to MVP  I was almost sure that, it's impossible to put it into App Store, but I decided to ask anyways.

Comment: @emil Or you could go through the simple way... :)

Comment: @Michael format is not so difficult to figure out. The only drawback of my solution is that app has to kill dock every time (still I'm looking for better solution)

Comment: oh wow, I'd call this the "shotgun method" ;)

Comment: *Walking around Apple's sandboxing* gets your app being rejected I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 5):

Not only is that file outside your sandbox, but its contents (e.g, the Dock preference keys) are an undocumented interface. An application that attempts to modify this file will not be approved for distribution through the App Store.